# SQL Matching Pattern

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I would like to find a pattern of 3-2 numbers followed by an X and 3-2 numbers. In other programs I would use REGEX, how can this be done in SQL?

Example:

```
**Input**
|NH_90x873_nyc_hi|
|Spring_Summer_908x780_Sam|
|Fall_Winter_pluto_890x80_Mike_LA_Earth|

**Output**
|90x873|
|908x780|
|890x80|
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to use regex with Redshift

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
select regexp_substr('NH_90x873_nyc_hi', '[0-9].+[0-9]');
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since input 1 and 3 has the desire sub string in 3rd and 4th position from the back

Comment: @sergiospizzirri updated my answer, please take a look and let me know if it won't work.